# With websocket and javascript concatenate in one objet two different coordinates

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am working on a real-time multiplayer game for two players. My project is composed of two files : one for the server (app.js) and one for the game (gamescript.js). I would like the two players, on two different computers, to be able to send their respective Y positions and their usernames from the « gamescript.js » file to the « app.js » file. I would like to be able to, on the server side, retrieve information from the two players and include them in an object. That object would then be sent back to the 2 players with their position and username, so that the game could be played in real time.

Thank you for your help.

The code of gamescript.js :

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
var socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:8888/');
let joueur;
let pseudo;
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", getMousePos);
function getMousePos(evt){
    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    if(joueurGauche){
        joueur1.y = evt.clientY - rect.top - joueur1.height/2;
        pseudo = 'much';
        socket.emit('joueur', {joueur: joueur1.y, pseudo: pseudo})
    } 
    if(!joueurGauche) {
        joueur2.y = evt.clientY - rect.top - joueur2.height/2;
        pseudo = "truc"
        socket.emit('joueur', {joueur: joueur2.y, pseudo: pseudo})
    }
    socket.on('coords', function(data){
        console.log('data : ',data)
    })
}
socket.on('position', function(coords){
    console.log('retour :', coords)
})
});
```

the code of app.js:

```
let joueur1Y;
let joueur2Y;
let racket = {};
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('New connection');
    console.log('id : ', socket.id)
    io.emit('for everyone', 'HipHipHip a new client has joined us !')


    socket.on('joueur', function(coords){
        raquetteArray = Object.keys(racket).map(key => racket[key]);
        joueur1Y = coords;
        console.log('test ', joueur1Y)
        io.emit('coords', raquetteArray)
        console.log('envoyé')

    });
```

Comment: What is the current result? Include the current result and any error messages in your question.

Comment: I don't have any error message but the object  that is sent back to gamescript.js is an empty array

Comment: Please indicate that in your question. That is probably caused by the racket object having no keys?